# virtual files such as /proc/uptime in java

Tags: java, file, virtual

Is it possible to create virtual files (such as /proc/uptime for exanple) in java? That is, the file does not really represent a physical entity on the hard disk, but when accessed, some process returns the content.

Thanks!

Comment: For your interest, I fail to find something useful in google or here. I believe that I am using the wrong keyword 'virtual file', but I have no idea how it is really called.

Comment: uptime is also a shell command in Linux and has a similar command in Windows. Just open a new process and say `uptime` on a Linux machine and `systeminfo | find "Time:"` on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) to create a virtual filesystem. When mounted, file system calls (e.g. when you execute `ls` in a shell) will end up calling your code.

Apparently there are some [Java bindings](http://code.google.com/p/javafuse/) for it as well.

Answer (score 0):

As a regular process, you cannot create a file like /proc/uptime, since it is exposed by the kernel.

You can try to create a named pipe that is a good way to communicate with a single process.  But even for that you'd have to jump out into JNA/JNI, or use the shell.